# Asynctask multiple consecutive URL requests in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httprequest, kotlin

I am having trouble with requesting multiple consecutive url http requests. My app is not crashing. Upon using the loadUrls() function in this code, it executes 6 url requests consecutively and store them in an array, however I can only see the first string response of the requests.

```
fun loadUrls(){
val locationInput = “AsiaWorldExpo”
val locationCoordinatesLong = 113.947
val locationCoordinatesLat = 22.2913
val myAPIKey = "REMOVED"
val transportMode = arrayListOf("&mode=driving" ,"&mode=walking", "&mode=bicycling",
        "&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus", "mode=transit&transit_mode=subway", "mode=transit&transit_mode=train")

var requestURLArray = ArrayList<String>()
for (i in 0 until transportMode.size) {

  requestURLArray.add("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins= " +
            "$locationCoordinatesLat,$locationCoordinatesLong &destinations=$locationInput ${transportMode[i]} &key= $myAPIKey")
}
MyAsyncTask().execute(requestURLArray[0],requestURLArray[1],requestURLArray[2]
        ,requestURLArray[3], requestURLArray[4], requestURLArray[5])
}

override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String { 
        try {
            val inString = ArrayList<String>()
            for (i in 0 until p0.size) {
                val url = URL(p0[i])

                val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                urlConnect.connectTimeout = 7000
                inString.add(ConvertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)) 
                publishProgress(inString[i])
                Log.d("APP_TEST", "" + p0[i]) //Added for debugging
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {}
            }
        }catch (r:Exception){}

        return " "
    }

override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
    try{
        val jsonObject = ArrayList<String>()
        for (i in 0 until values.size){

            jsonObject.add(values[i]!!)
            Log.d("Testing", "" + values[i]) //Added for debugging

        }
        idTextView2.text =  jsonObject[1]
```

> EDIT: The above line of code does not print out the Text View to UI from jsonObject[1] up to jsonObject[5]. Only jsonObject[0] works.

```
    }catch (e:Exception){}
}
override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
}
}
    fun ConvertStreamToString(inputStream: InputStream): String{
    val bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
    var line =""
    var allString=""
    try{
        do{
            line=bufferReader.readLine()
            if (line!=null){
                allString+=line
            }
        } while (line!=null)
        inputStream.close()
    } catch (e:Exception){}
    return allString
}
```

Here is the updated Logcat:

> 08-18 09:51:21.697 2660-3883/com.google.android.gms W/DriveInitializer: Background init thread ended
>
> 08-18 09:52:00.405 1369-1409/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 772788 , only wrote 772560
>
> 08-18 09:52:00.433 3297-3320/com.companyname.emitless2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7ebacc5cc6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7ebadbdb9d00)
>
> 08-18 09:52:00.441 3297-3320/com.companyname.emitless2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7ebacc5cc6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7ebadbdb9d00)
>
> 08-18 09:52:00.590 3297-3894/com.companyname.emitless2 D/APP_TEST: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins= 22.29129833333333,113.94699999999999 &destinations=AsiaWorldExpo &mode=driving &key= "REMOVED"
>
> 08-18 09:52:00.590 3297-3297/com.companyname.emitless2 D/Testing: {   "destination_addresses" : [ "Cheong Wing Rd, Chek Lap Kok, Hong Kong" ],   "origin_addresses" : [ "Yi Tung Rd, Tung Chung, Hong Kong" ],   "rows" : [      {         "elements" : [            {               "distance" : {                  "text" : "5.9 km",                  "value" : 5948               },               "duration" : {                  "text" : "9 mins",                  "value" : 541               },               "status" : "OK"            }         ]      }   ],   "status" : "OK"}
>
> 08-18 09:52:01.286 3297-3894/com.companyname.emitless2 D/APP_TEST: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins= 22.29129833333333,113.94699999999999 &destinations=AsiaWorldExpo &mode=walking &key= "REMOVED"
>
> 08-18 09:52:01.287 3297-3297/com.companyname.emitless2 D/Testing: {   "destination_addresses" : [ "Cheong Wing Rd, Chek Lap Kok, Hong Kong" ],   "origin_addresses" : [ "Yi Tung Rd, Tung Chung, Hong Kong" ],   "rows" : [      {         "elements" : [            {               "distance" : {                  "text" : "5.9 km",                  "value" : 5948               },               "duration" : {                  "text" : "9 mins",                  "value" : 541               },               "status" : "OK"            }         ]      }   ],   "status" : "OK"}
>
> 08-18 09:52:01.865 3297-3894/com.companyname.emitless2 D/APP_TEST: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins= 22.29129833333333,113.94699999999999 &destinations=AsiaWorldExpo &mode=bicycling &key= "REMOVED"
>
> 08-18 09:52:01.865 3297-3297/com.companyname.emitless2 D/Testing: {   "destination_addresses" : [ "Cheong Wing Rd, Chek Lap Kok, Hong Kong" ],   "origin_addresses" : [ "Yi Tung Rd, Tung Chung, Hong Kong" ],   "rows" : [      {         "elements" : [            {               "distance" : {                  "text" : "5.9 km",                  "value" : 5948               },               "duration" : {                  "text" : "9 mins",                  "value" : 541               },               "status" : "OK"            }         ]      }   ],   "status" : "OK"}
>
> 08-18 09:52:02.409 1672-1672/system_process W/WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@7d40824
>
> 08-18 09:52:02.495 3297-3320/com.companyname.emitless2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7ebacc5cc6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7ebadbdb9d00)
>
> 08-18 09:52:02.540 3297-3320/com.companyname.emitless2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7ebacc5cc6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7ebadbdb9d00)
>
> 08-18 09:52:03.632 1369-1410/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 1080247 , only wrote 927360
>
> 08-18 09:52:04.458 1672-1672/system_process W/WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@f7c5953

Comment: I have removed the API key from your code. Consider it leaked anyway, so I'd suggest disabling it and getting a new one. You should almost never post API keys on StackOverflow or other public platforms.

Comment: Thanks very much for that, was careless

Comment: can you please provide **LogCat**?

Comment: **also add `e.printStackTrace()` to your `catch` block to get *Logcat***

Comment: added Logcat in the post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new instance named inString of type ArrayList on every iteration. So when you create new instance and add an item to it, that item is always at 0. Fix it by moving the arrayList instance creation outside of loop.

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String { 
 try {
    val inString = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in 0 until p0.size) {
        val url = URL(p0[i]) 
        val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        urlConnect.connectTimeout = 7000          
        inString.add(ConvertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)) 
        publishProgress(inString[i])
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500)
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {}
    }
}catch (e:Exception){}
return " "
}
```

Comment: Super nice catch!

Comment: Nice catch. But still does not print out jsonObject[1] to jsonObject[5]. Please check out updated post and everything. I have made amendments as you have suggested. Thank you for your time.